# Automatically mount bucket with s3fs on boot

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, boot, fstab, fuse, s3fs

I use an Amazon S3 bucket to deliver some of my server's content.
I was able to mount it successfully, and grant Apache rights over it, but can't get it mounted properly at reboot.

I updated my **`/etc/fstab`** with this line, but nothing happens when I boot

```
s3fs#my-bucket-name /mnt/s3_bucket fuse allow_other,umask=227,uid=33,gid=33,use_cache=/root/cache 0 0
```

So, I tried another way, commented said line, and just put my command line in **`/etc/init.d/local`** :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
s3fs -o allow_other,uid=33,gid=33,umask=227,use_cache=/root/cache my-bucket-name /mnt/s3_bucket
```

... didn't work either.

I ended up putting a **`cron`**, and now, it works, but it feels terribly hacky to me, and I wonder why mounting it at start doesn't work.

```
//Crontab
*/10 * * * * ~/mountBucket.sh 1>/dev/null

//Mount script
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ -d /mnt/s3_bucket/someBucketVirtualDirectoryName ]] ; then echo 'Bucket already mounted' ; else s3fs -o allow_other,uid=33,gid=33,umask=227,use_cache=/root/cache my-bucket-name /mnt/s3_bucket ; fi 1>/dev/null
```

Is there something I missed ?

*I'm Using Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, with Fuse 2.9.2*

---

EDIT :
Here is another unrelated, yet important performance issue I had to figure out by myself:

If your system includes locate and/or mlocate (and Ubuntu 14.04 does), you may want to add an exception, so that it does NOT scan your bucket.
I had to modify both my `/etc/updatedb.conf` and `/etc/cron.daily/locate`, adding " `/mnt/my-bucket-name"` to `PRUNEPATHS` and `" fuse.s3fs"` to `PRUNEFS`
I suppose adding `fuse.s3fs should be enough`, but... no time to take risks right now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to add _netdev to your fstab:

`s3fs#my-bucket-name /mnt/s3_bucket fuse _netdev,allow_other,umask=227,uid=33,gid=33,use_cache=/root/cache 0 0`

Comment: Looks like it's as simple as this.  Too bad this option was hardly ever mentioned, and nowhere explained in any of the tutorials or articles I found, while it seems absolutely necessary.
Big thanks.

Comment: it's actually in s3fs's README https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse

Comment: I noticed it _after_, but it's not explained on that page.  There's one answer about it in the FAQ, which is quite clear, but I'm not used to Github enough to know pages include a FAQ. Half of the other blog/tutorial/forums pages I browsed didn't include the _netdev option when showing a fstab line, and for the other half, it's here among other stuff, but without explaination (while allow_other is often higlighted).  Therefore, I had no idea of how important it could be. IMO, simple questions like this should be answered on SE anyway. Immediate google answers to basics helps going further

Answer (score 0):

for me, using Amazon Linux 2 this worked:

```
s3fs#my.bucket.name  /mount/path fuse _netdev,allow_other,iam_role,url=http://s3.amazonaws.com 0 0
```

From:
https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/issues/1138

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

s3fs#my.bucket.name

That hash character after s3fs... that effectively stopped my EC2 from booting. I am not particularly familiar with servers, probably shouldn't be allowed near them, but I wanted to check if that syntax is actually correct for Ubuntu 20.04?

Yes - sorry this is 5yrs too late for a question... just now trying to mount S3 on reboot in AWS...

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/546903)